# Can I apply Tomek links on only 2 classes out of 4 in a multiclass classification problem?

Tags: classification

I am sorry if this sounds dumb, but I am not sure whether I can apply Tomek links on just 2 classes out of 4. All the usage examples that I found in the internet are using Tomek links for binary classification problem.

My multiclass classification problem is to classify whether an internet traffic is a legitimate connection or any type of attack. There are 4 classes: normal, DoS, Probe, and R2L. Here is the distribution of classes
[image]

I am planning to use Tomek links on "normal" class and undersample it so that its amount is nearly equal to that of "DoS". Then apply SMOTE on "R2L" and "Probe" to increase their ratio over the "DoS" class at least to 0.5.

My question is: 1) Is it possible to do this? 2) Does this even sound legitimate?

By the way, I am ignoring the "U2R" since there are too few samples of this class.